# centos7サーバーでSSH接続をすると50秒で切断されてしまう

Tags: centos, ssh

TeratermやWinSCPでCentOS7サーバーに接続すると50秒で切断されてしまいます。
当該事象が発生するのは、このサーバー1台で他のサーバーは正常です。
そのため、TeratermやWinSCPの設定ではないと思っていますまた、設定も確認しています。

サーバー側の設定としては、sshd_configの設定を2か所を以下のように変更し、
sshdを再起動（systemctl restart sshd）しましたが、結果は変わりません。

```
ClientAliveInterval　180   
ClientAliveCountMax 3
```

関係ないと思うのですが、外部から接続できないように、ルーターにIP制限を掛けて、特定のIPしかアクセスできない状態にしましたが、やはり結果は変わりませんでした。
どなたか、同じ事象で解決された方はおりますでしょうか。
ご教示いただけると幸いです。

以下がサーバのログです。（secure）

```
Jul  1 00:07:59 APOLLO sshd[3545]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 00:08:02 APOLLO sshd[3541]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 00:08:14 APOLLO polkitd[668]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:3647:234463 (system bus name :1.93 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Jul  1 00:08:39 APOLLO polkit-agent-helper-1[3657]: pam_unix(polkit-1:auth): conversation failed
Jul  1 00:08:39 APOLLO polkit-agent-helper-1[3657]: pam_unix(polkit-1:auth): auth could not identify password for [root]
Jul  1 00:08:39 APOLLO polkit-agent-helper-1[3657]: pam_succeed_if(polkit-1:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"
Jul  1 00:08:39 APOLLO polkitd[668]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:3647:234463 (system bus name :1.93, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Jul  1 00:08:39 APOLLO polkitd[668]: Operator of unix-process:3647:234463 FAILED to authenticate to gain authorization for action org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units for system-bus-name::1.94 [<unknown>] (owned by unix-user:ij*********)
Jul  1 00:08:46 APOLLO polkitd[668]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:3664:237631 (system bus name :1.98 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Jul  1 00:08:50 APOLLO polkitd[668]: Operator of unix-process:3664:237631 successfully authenticated as unix-user:root to gain ONE-SHOT authorization for action org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units for system-bus-name::1.99 [systemctl restart sshd] (owned by unix-user:ij*********)
Jul  1 00:08:50 APOLLO polkitd[668]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:3664:237631 (system bus name :1.98, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Jul  1 00:08:51 APOLLO sshd[3545]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 00:09:02 APOLLO sshd[3682]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 00:09:53 APOLLO sshd[3682]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 00:10:04 APOLLO sshd[3741]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 00:10:55 APOLLO sshd[3741]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 00:11:14 APOLLO sshd[3802]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 00:11:17 APOLLO sshd[3541]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 00:12:12 APOLLO sshd[3802]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 00:12:30 APOLLO sshd[3894]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 00:13:25 APOLLO sshd[3894]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 00:13:44 APOLLO sshd[3943]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 00:14:39 APOLLO sshd[3943]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 00:14:58 APOLLO sshd[4004]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 00:15:52 APOLLO sshd[4004]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 00:16:02 APOLLO sshd[4052]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 00:16:54 APOLLO sshd[4052]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 00:17:04 APOLLO sshd[4113]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 00:17:56 APOLLO sshd[4113]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 00:18:06 APOLLO sshd[4162]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 00:18:57 APOLLO sshd[4162]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 00:19:08 APOLLO sshd[4223]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 00:19:59 APOLLO sshd[4223]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 00:20:09 APOLLO sshd[4278]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 00:21:01 APOLLO sshd[4278]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 00:21:11 APOLLO sshd[4339]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 00:22:02 APOLLO sshd[4339]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 00:22:13 APOLLO sshd[4387]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 00:23:04 APOLLO sshd[4387]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 00:23:15 APOLLO sshd[4448]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 00:24:07 APOLLO sshd[4448]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 00:24:17 APOLLO sshd[4496]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 00:25:09 APOLLO sshd[4496]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 00:25:19 APOLLO sshd[4558]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 00:26:11 APOLLO sshd[4558]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 00:26:21 APOLLO sshd[4606]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 00:27:12 APOLLO sshd[4606]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 00:27:22 APOLLO sshd[4667]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 00:28:14 APOLLO sshd[4667]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 00:28:24 APOLLO sshd[4716]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 00:29:15 APOLLO sshd[4716]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 00:29:26 APOLLO sshd[4777]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 00:30:18 APOLLO sshd[4777]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 00:30:28 APOLLO sshd[4830]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 00:31:19 APOLLO sshd[4830]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 00:31:29 APOLLO sshd[4891]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 00:32:21 APOLLO sshd[4891]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 00:32:31 APOLLO sshd[4984]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 00:33:22 APOLLO sshd[4984]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 09:21:47 APOLLO sshd[25313]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 09:23:46 APOLLO sshd[25313]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 09:23:50 APOLLO sshd[25359]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 09:23:56 APOLLO sshd[25450]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 09:24:36 APOLLO su: pam_unix(su:auth): authentication failure; logname=ij********* uid=1001 euid=0 tty=pts/0 ruser=ij********* rhost=  user=root
Jul  1 09:24:36 APOLLO su: pam_succeed_if(su:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"
Jul  1 09:24:48 APOLLO sshd[25450]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 09:24:48 APOLLO su: pam_unix(su:auth): authentication failure; logname=ij********* uid=1001 euid=0 tty=pts/0 ruser=ij********* rhost=  user=root
Jul  1 09:24:48 APOLLO su: pam_succeed_if(su:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"
Jul  1 09:24:58 APOLLO sshd[25508]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 09:25:07 APOLLO su: pam_unix(su:auth): authentication failure; logname=ij********* uid=1001 euid=0 tty=pts/0 ruser=ij********* rhost=  user=root
Jul  1 09:25:07 APOLLO su: pam_succeed_if(su:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"
Jul  1 09:25:50 APOLLO sshd[25508]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 09:26:00 APOLLO sshd[25359]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 09:26:01 APOLLO sshd[25574]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 09:26:53 APOLLO sshd[25574]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 09:27:01 APOLLO sshd[25620]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 09:27:04 APOLLO sshd[25667]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 09:27:10 APOLLO su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by ij*********(uid=1001)
Jul  1 09:27:56 APOLLO sshd[25667]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 09:28:06 APOLLO sshd[25765]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 09:28:51 APOLLO su: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user root
Jul  1 09:28:51 APOLLO sshd[25620]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 09:28:58 APOLLO sshd[25765]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 09:29:08 APOLLO sshd[25814]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 09:30:09 APOLLO sshd[25814]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 09:30:20 APOLLO sshd[25915]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 09:31:11 APOLLO sshd[25915]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 09:31:21 APOLLO sshd[25976]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 09:31:36 APOLLO sshd[25991]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 09:31:44 APOLLO su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by ij*********(uid=1001)
Jul  1 09:32:13 APOLLO sshd[25976]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ij*********
Jul  1 09:32:24 APOLLO sshd[26102]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ij********* by (uid=0)
Jul  1 09:32:45 APOLLO su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by ij*********(uid=0)
Jul  1 09:33:15 APOLLO sshd[26102]: pam_unix(sshd:session):
```

下記のWINSCPと該当するSECUREログを抜粋

```
Jul  1 09:54:19 APOLLO sshd[27049]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ijsRa2pS
Jul  1 09:54:28 APOLLO sshd[27097]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ijsRa2pS by (uid=0)
Jul  1 09:55:20 APOLLO sshd[27097]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ijsRa2pS
Jul  1 09:55:30 APOLLO sshd[27158]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ijsRa2pS by (uid=0)
Jul  1 09:56:22 APOLLO sshd[27158]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ijsRa2pS
Jul  1 10:48:53 APOLLO sshd[29187]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ijsRa2pS by (uid=0)
```

また、以下がWINSCPのログです。

```
* 2023-07-01 09:54:18.927 (ESshFatal) サーバがネットワーク接続を閉じました
. 2023-07-01 09:54:26.218 Looking up host "153.1.1.149" for SSH connection
. 2023-07-01 09:54:26.218 Connecting to 153.1.1.149 port 22
. 2023-07-01 09:54:26.274 We claim version: SSH-2.0-WinSCP_release_5.19.5
. 2023-07-01 09:54:26.315 Remote version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
. 2023-07-01 09:54:26.315 Using SSH protocol version 2
. 2023-07-01 09:54:26.316 Have a known host key of type ssh-ed25519
. 2023-07-01 09:54:26.383 Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256
. 2023-07-01 09:54:26.768 Server also has ecdsa-sha2-nistp256/ssh-rsa host keys, but we don't know any of them
. 2023-07-01 09:54:26.768 Host key fingerprint is:
. 2023-07-01 09:54:26.768 ssh-ed25519 255 96:39:1e:51:f0:a8:b5:f0:20:38:34:0e:e7:18:2a:86 o1zXSkn8MA2UzlvZGxCRKH4ymwPu532QgCoXFtWJ0oA=
. 2023-07-01 09:54:26.775 Host key matches cached key
. 2023-07-01 09:54:26.776 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) [aes256-ctr] outbound encryption
. 2023-07-01 09:54:26.776 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 outbound MAC algorithm
. 2023-07-01 09:54:26.776 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) [aes256-ctr] inbound encryption
. 2023-07-01 09:54:26.776 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 inbound MAC algorithm
! 2023-07-01 09:54:27.045 Using username "ijsRa2pS".
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.106 Server offered these authentication methods: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.106 Using SSPI from SECUR32.DLL
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.106 Trying gssapi-with-mic...
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.106 Attempting GSSAPI authentication
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.124 GSSAPI authentication request refused
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.124 Server offered these authentication methods: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.124 Prompt (password, "SSH password", <no instructions>, "パスワード(&P): ")
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.124 Using stored password.
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.157 Sent password
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.279 Access granted
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.280 Opening main session channel
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.330 Opened main channel
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.368 Started a shell/command
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.429 Doing startup conversation with host.
> 2023-07-01 09:54:27.469 Type: SSH_FXP_INIT, Size: 5, Number: -1
< 2023-07-01 09:54:27.489 Type: SSH_FXP_VERSION, Size: 150, Number: -1
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.490 SFTP version 3 negotiated.
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.490 Unknown server extension posix-rename@openssh.com="1"
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.490 Supports statvfs@openssh.com extension version "2"
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.490 Unknown server extension fstatvfs@openssh.com="2"
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.490 Supports hardlink@openssh.com extension version "1"
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.490 Unknown server extension fsync@openssh.com="1"
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.490 We believe the server has signed timestamps bug
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.490 We will use UTF-8 strings until server sends an invalid UTF-8 string as with SFTP version 3 and older UTF-8 strings are not mandatory
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.490 Limiting packet size to OpenSSH sftp-server limit of 262148 bytes
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.490 Changing directory to "/var".
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.490 Getting real path for '/var'
> 2023-07-01 09:54:27.490 Type: SSH_FXP_REALPATH, Size: 13, Number: 37623312
< 2023-07-01 09:54:27.497 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 29, Number: 37623312
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.497 Real path is '/var'
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.497 Trying to open directory "/var".
> 2023-07-01 09:54:27.497 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 13, Number: 37623559
< 2023-07-01 09:54:27.554 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 37, Number: 37623559
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.554 Getting current directory name.
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.658 Directory content loaded from cache.
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.775 Cached directory not reloaded.
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.815 Listing directory "/var".
> 2023-07-01 09:54:27.815 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 13, Number: 37623819
< 2023-07-01 09:54:27.847 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 13, Number: 37623819
> 2023-07-01 09:54:27.847 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 13, Number: 37624076
< 2023-07-01 09:54:27.894 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 2825, Number: 37624076
> 2023-07-01 09:54:27.894 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 13, Number: 37624332
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.894 Reading symlink "run".
> 2023-07-01 09:54:27.894 Type: SSH_FXP_READLINK, Size: 17, Number: 37624595
> 2023-07-01 09:54:27.895 Type: SSH_FXP_STAT, Size: 17, Number: 37624849
< 2023-07-01 09:54:27.899 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 37624332
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.899 Storing reserved response
< 2023-07-01 09:54:27.899 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 33, Number: 37624595
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.899 Link resolved to "../run".
< 2023-07-01 09:54:27.904 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 37, Number: 37624849
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.904 Reading symlink "lock".
> 2023-07-01 09:54:27.904 Type: SSH_FXP_READLINK, Size: 18, Number: 37625107
> 2023-07-01 09:54:27.904 Type: SSH_FXP_STAT, Size: 18, Number: 37625361
< 2023-07-01 09:54:27.913 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 43, Number: 37625107
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.913 Link resolved to "../run/lock".
< 2023-07-01 09:54:27.913 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 37, Number: 37625361
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.939 Reading symlink "mail".
> 2023-07-01 09:54:27.939 Type: SSH_FXP_READLINK, Size: 18, Number: 37625619
> 2023-07-01 09:54:27.940 Type: SSH_FXP_STAT, Size: 18, Number: 37625873
< 2023-07-01 09:54:27.946 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 41, Number: 37625619
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.946 Link resolved to "spool/mail".
< 2023-07-01 09:54:27.946 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 37, Number: 37625873
< 2023-07-01 09:54:27.955 Status code: 1
> 2023-07-01 09:54:27.955 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 13, Number: 37626116
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.955 ..;d;0;2020-04-12T02:31:11.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];r-xr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.955 lib;d;0;2020-04-12T02:33:48.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.955 run;l;0;2016-01-14T10:10:25.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxrwxrwx;1
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.955 lock;l;0;2016-01-14T10:10:25.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxrwxrwx;1
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.955 log;d;0;2023-06-30T18:08:01.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.955 adm;d;0;2018-04-11T04:59:55.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.955 cache;d;0;2023-06-30T14:29:52.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.955 db;d;0;2020-04-12T02:31:25.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.955 empty;d;0;2018-04-11T04:59:55.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.956 games;d;0;2018-04-11T04:59:55.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.956 gopher;d;0;2018-04-11T04:59:55.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.956 local;d;0;2018-04-11T04:59:55.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.956 mail;l;0;2020-04-12T02:31:12.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxrwxrwx;1
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.956 nis;d;0;2018-04-11T04:59:55.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.956 opt;d;0;2018-04-11T04:59:55.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.956 preserve;d;0;2018-04-11T04:59:55.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.956 spool;d;0;2018-04-11T04:59:55.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.956 tmp;d;0;2023-07-01T00:32:07.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxrwxrwt;1
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.956 yp;d;0;2018-04-11T04:59:55.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.956 kerberos;d;0;2019-09-13T18:05:33.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.956 var;d;0;2016-01-14T10:12:33.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.956 crash;d;0;2019-08-08T11:41:21.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.956 account;d;0;2017-08-03T09:00:53.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.956 .updated;-;163;2020-04-12T02:31:12.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rw-r--r--;2
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.956 www;d;0;2023-06-30T14:57:55.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:54:27.956 ftp;d;0;2020-05-28T12:07:56.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:54:28.039 Startup conversation with host finished.
. 2023-07-01 09:55:19.933 Remote side unexpectedly closed network connection
* 2023-07-01 09:55:19.933 (ESshFatal) サーバがネットワーク接続を閉じました
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.159 Looking up host "153.1.1.149" for SSH connection
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.160 Connecting to 153.1.1.149 port 22
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.224 We claim version: SSH-2.0-WinSCP_release_5.19.5
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.225 Remote version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.226 Using SSH protocol version 2
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.228 Have a known host key of type ssh-ed25519
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.238 Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.418 Server also has ecdsa-sha2-nistp256/ssh-rsa host keys, but we don't know any of them
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.418 Host key fingerprint is:
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.418 ssh-ed25519 255 96:39:1e:51:f0:a8:b5:f0:20:38:34:0e:e7:18:2a:86 o1zXSkn8MA2UzlvZGxCRKH4ymwPu532QgCoXFtWJ0oA=
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.479 Host key matches cached key
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.479 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) [aes256-ctr] outbound encryption
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.479 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 outbound MAC algorithm
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.479 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) [aes256-ctr] inbound encryption
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.479 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 inbound MAC algorithm
! 2023-07-01 09:55:29.526 Using username "ijsRa2pS".
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.561 Server offered these authentication methods: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.561 Using SSPI from SECUR32.DLL
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.561 Trying gssapi-with-mic...
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.561 Attempting GSSAPI authentication
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.573 GSSAPI authentication request refused
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.573 Server offered these authentication methods: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.574 Prompt (password, "SSH password", <no instructions>, "パスワード(&P): ")
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.574 Using stored password.
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.603 Sent password
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.735 Access granted
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.735 Opening main session channel
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.783 Opened main channel
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.824 Started a shell/command
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.870 Doing startup conversation with host.
> 2023-07-01 09:55:29.913 Type: SSH_FXP_INIT, Size: 5, Number: -1
< 2023-07-01 09:55:29.958 Type: SSH_FXP_VERSION, Size: 150, Number: -1
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.958 SFTP version 3 negotiated.
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.958 Unknown server extension posix-rename@openssh.com="1"
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.958 Supports statvfs@openssh.com extension version "2"
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.958 Unknown server extension fstatvfs@openssh.com="2"
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.958 Supports hardlink@openssh.com extension version "1"
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.958 Unknown server extension fsync@openssh.com="1"
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.958 We believe the server has signed timestamps bug
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.958 We will use UTF-8 strings until server sends an invalid UTF-8 string as with SFTP version 3 and older UTF-8 strings are not mandatory
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.958 Limiting packet size to OpenSSH sftp-server limit of 262148 bytes
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.958 Changing directory to "/var".
. 2023-07-01 09:55:29.958 Getting real path for '/var'
> 2023-07-01 09:55:29.958 Type: SSH_FXP_REALPATH, Size: 13, Number: 37626384
< 2023-07-01 09:55:30.025 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 29, Number: 37626384
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.025 Real path is '/var'
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.025 Trying to open directory "/var".
> 2023-07-01 09:55:30.025 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 13, Number: 37626631
< 2023-07-01 09:55:30.055 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 37, Number: 37626631
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.055 Getting current directory name.
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.156 Directory content loaded from cache.
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.276 Cached directory not reloaded.
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.299 Listing directory "/var".
> 2023-07-01 09:55:30.299 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 13, Number: 37626891
< 2023-07-01 09:55:30.307 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 13, Number: 37626891
> 2023-07-01 09:55:30.307 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 13, Number: 37627148
< 2023-07-01 09:55:30.320 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 2825, Number: 37627148
> 2023-07-01 09:55:30.321 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 13, Number: 37627404
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.321 Reading symlink "run".
> 2023-07-01 09:55:30.321 Type: SSH_FXP_READLINK, Size: 17, Number: 37627667
> 2023-07-01 09:55:30.321 Type: SSH_FXP_STAT, Size: 17, Number: 37627921
< 2023-07-01 09:55:30.341 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 37627404
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.341 Storing reserved response
< 2023-07-01 09:55:30.341 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 33, Number: 37627667
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.341 Link resolved to "../run".
< 2023-07-01 09:55:30.355 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 37, Number: 37627921
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.355 Reading symlink "lock".
> 2023-07-01 09:55:30.355 Type: SSH_FXP_READLINK, Size: 18, Number: 37628179
> 2023-07-01 09:55:30.355 Type: SSH_FXP_STAT, Size: 18, Number: 37628433
< 2023-07-01 09:55:30.360 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 43, Number: 37628179
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.360 Link resolved to "../run/lock".
< 2023-07-01 09:55:30.360 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 37, Number: 37628433
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.376 Reading symlink "mail".
> 2023-07-01 09:55:30.376 Type: SSH_FXP_READLINK, Size: 18, Number: 37628691
> 2023-07-01 09:55:30.376 Type: SSH_FXP_STAT, Size: 18, Number: 37628945
< 2023-07-01 09:55:30.393 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 41, Number: 37628691
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.393 Link resolved to "spool/mail".
< 2023-07-01 09:55:30.393 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 37, Number: 37628945
< 2023-07-01 09:55:30.423 Status code: 1
> 2023-07-01 09:55:30.423 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 13, Number: 37629188
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.423 ..;d;0;2020-04-12T02:31:11.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];r-xr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.424 lib;d;0;2020-04-12T02:33:48.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.424 run;l;0;2016-01-14T10:10:25.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxrwxrwx;1
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.424 lock;l;0;2016-01-14T10:10:25.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxrwxrwx;1
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.424 log;d;0;2023-06-30T18:08:01.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.424 adm;d;0;2018-04-11T04:59:55.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.424 cache;d;0;2023-06-30T14:29:52.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.424 db;d;0;2020-04-12T02:31:25.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.424 empty;d;0;2018-04-11T04:59:55.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.424 games;d;0;2018-04-11T04:59:55.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.424 gopher;d;0;2018-04-11T04:59:55.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.424 local;d;0;2018-04-11T04:59:55.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.424 mail;l;0;2020-04-12T02:31:12.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxrwxrwx;1
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.424 nis;d;0;2018-04-11T04:59:55.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.424 opt;d;0;2018-04-11T04:59:55.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.424 preserve;d;0;2018-04-11T04:59:55.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.424 spool;d;0;2018-04-11T04:59:55.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.424 tmp;d;0;2023-07-01T00:32:07.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxrwxrwt;1
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.424 yp;d;0;2018-04-11T04:59:55.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.424 kerberos;d;0;2019-09-13T18:05:33.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.424 var;d;0;2016-01-14T10:12:33.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.424 crash;d;0;2019-08-08T11:41:21.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.424 account;d;0;2017-08-03T09:00:53.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.424 .updated;-;163;2020-04-12T02:31:12.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rw-r--r--;2
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.424 www;d;0;2023-06-30T14:57:55.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.424 ftp;d;0;2020-05-28T12:07:56.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2023-07-01 09:55:30.479 Startup conversation with host finished.
. 2023-07-01 09:56:22.435 Remote side unexpectedly closed network connection
* 2023-07-01 09:56:22.436 (ESshFatal) サーバがネットワーク接続を閉じました
```

Comment: 切断時に何かしらのエラーメッセージは表示されないでしょうか？また、Tera TermとWinSCPの通信ログ、および、サーバー側のSSHサーバーのログに切断時のメッセージはありませんか？それらの情報があれば、質問文に追加してください。

Comment: ご案内ありがとうございます。secureログとWINSCPログを追記しました。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: サーバー側のログとクライアント側のログで時刻があってないようです。どちらかが大幅に時刻がずれていると言うことは無いでしょうか？時刻同期が両方とも正常なら、なるべく同じ通信に対するログの方が状況が把握しやすいです。

Comment: クライアントサーバー間にルーター等があるのであれば、そこでTCP無通信のタイムアウトが短く設定されているかも知れません。WinSCPの「高度なサイトの設定」の「接続」にある「接続の保持」はどのような設定になっていますか？もし「オフ」なら、30秒毎に「ダミーコマンドを送信する」にした場合、現象が改善されたりしないでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。WinSCPの設定をご案内の通り変更したところ、切断されないように改善しました。一方でteraterm側では不思議な挙動をします。teratermもKeep-aliveの設定をしたことで接続が維持されるようになりました。ところが、数分程度掛かるsqlを投げると、やはり接続が切れてしまいます。ルーターはGMOクラウドサービスのNATになるのですが、TCPの設定は特になく、正常なものと同一なのでおそらくNATでは無いとは思います。

Comment: おそらく、クライアントとサーバーの間にあるなんらかの装置で無通信タイムアウトが短いのだと思われます。サーバー側だけでなくクライアント側の場合もあります。ただ、他のサーバーで現象が発生せず、一切違いがないとなるとクラウドサービスでも借りるタイミングで差異があるとかかも知れません。ここら辺はクライアントサーバー含めて詳しい経路がわからないと難しいかと思われます。ひとまず、sshd_configで`ClientAliveInterval 30`などとすれば、とりあえずの解決ができるかも知れません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。NATを新しく立ち上げ、サーバーをイメージから新しく構築したのですが、同じ事象が発生しました。おそらくサーバー側の設定の何かだと思います。ただ、教えていただいたダミーコマンドで今回の作業は乗り切ることができました。原因はわかりませんが、作業は完了できたので、クローズとしたいと思います。ご教示いただきありがとうございました。

Comment: 解決した場合には、コメント欄で終わらせずに、どのようにした解決したのかを  **個別の回答** として投稿してもらうと、同じような問題で困った人の助けになります。当サイトでは [自己回答も歓迎しています](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)。